# Pipe for three commands

Tags: command-line, pipe

In the manual of `sudo` I need to search for `-k` so I tried this:

```
man sudo | grep '\-k'
```

But it would result a paragraph be half-written on the output:

```
sudo -h | -K | -k | -V
             Similar to the -k option, except that it removes the user's
 -k, --reset-timestamp
```

Instead I tried printing the whole manual and color the search phrase with:

```
man sudo | grep '\-k\|$'
```

But since the manual page is too long, I can't scroll up enough to reach the beginning of the output (Note: I don't want to change the Scrollback lines in the profile settings of Terminal).

So I need to use `more` or `less` commands, to be able to reveal the output by page, so I tried:

```
man sudo | grep '\-k\|$' | less
```

But of course it doesn't work, because pipe runs the 2nd command on the 1st command.

Any idea how to redirect pipe?

Or make `grep` print whole paragraph instead of one line? (the lines are based on Terminal's window size)

Comment: I also find `man sudo | grep -n "\|$" | grep 15:` very useful, it prints line 15 in the sudo manual page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`man` by default already uses `less` as a pager to display the manual page content.

Now `less` already has a built-in search and highlight feature, so you don't need an external tool like `grep` for that.

Simply open the manpage by running `man sudo` in a shell, then type `/-k` (press <kbd>/</kbd> and type your search pattern). `less` will now highlight wherever this regular expression matches in the document and also jump directly to the first occurrence.

You can then navigate to the next match by typing `n` (press <kbd>N</kbd>) or the previous match by typing `N` (press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>).

---

More general, if you want to view `grep`'s  output with colorful highlighting in `less`, you must use `grep --color=always` (to always emit color codes, even when not outputting to a terminal but a pipe) and `less -R` (to interpret color escapes instead of printing the control characters):

```
man sudo | grep --color=always '\-k\|$' | less -R
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `grep`'s `-A`, `-B` and `-C` switches to catch the surrounding lines

```
man grep | grep '\-[ABC]' -A2

   -A NUM, --after-context=NUM
          Print NUM lines of trailing context after matching lines.  Places a line containing a group separator (described under --group-separator) between contiguous groups of matches.  With the -o or
          --only-matching option, this has no effect and a warning is given.

   -B NUM, --before-context=NUM
          Print NUM lines of leading context before matching lines.  Places a line containing a group separator (described under --group-separator) between contiguous groups of matches.  With the -o or
          --only-matching option, this has no effect and a warning is given.

   -C NUM, -NUM, --context=NUM
          Print  NUM  lines  of  output  context.   Places  a line containing a group separator (described under --group-separator) between contiguous groups of matches.  With the -o or --only-matching
          option, this has no effect and a warning is given.
```

In your case:

```
man sudo | grep '\-k' -A5 -B2
```

This is of course not perfect as you don't know how many lines are needed, but it may still help you find what you need.

Comment: `grep -A5 -B5` is actually just `grep -C5` ;-D --- You don't know how many lines you will need to get the whole paragraph though.

Comment: This is a `grep` solution because the OP used `grep`. But the less' search function is actually the proper solution ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the `most` pager would satisfy your requirements. Try

```
export PAGER=most
man sudo
/-k
```

Comment: `s@s-N ~ $ export PAGER=most`   then
`s@s-N ~ $ man sudo`   returns error
`man: can't execute most: No such file or directory`

Comment: Install `most` from your favorite package manager. For example `sudo aptitude install most`.

Comment: There is no need to install anything. You can already search in man using `/´.